# error when passing pointer to struct to function in c

Tags: c, struct, gettimeofday

I'm trying to pass pointers to two `struct timevals` to a function that would output the elapsed time between the two in a C program. However, even if I dereference these pointers, nvcc throws the error "expression must have class type" (this is a CUDA program). Here is the relevant code from main():

```
struct timeval begin, end;
if (tflag) { HostStartTimer(&begin) };
// CUDA Kernel execution
if (tflag) { HostStopTimer(&begin, &end); }
```

And the function definition for HostStopTimer():

```
void HostStopTimer(struct timeval *begin, stuct timeval *end) {
    long elapsed;
    gettimeofday(end, NULL);
    elapsed = ((*end.tv_sec - *begin.tv_sec)*1000000 + *end.tv_usec - *begin.tv_usec);
    printf("Host elapsed time: %ldus\n", elapsed);
 }
```

The line causing the error is the assignment to `elapsed`. I don't have much experience using structs in C, much less passing pointers to structs to functions, so I'm not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: try:     elapsed = ((end->tv_sec - begin->tv_sec)*1000000 + end->tv_usec - begin->tv_usec);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator, so expressions like `*end.tv_sec` attempt to first evaluate `end.tv_sec` (which isn't possible since `end` is a pointer) and then dereference the result.

You should use `(*end).tv_sec` or `end->tv_sec` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should write `elapsed = (((*end).tv_sec - (*begin).tv_sec)*1000000 + (*end).tv_usec - (*begin).tv_usec);` or use the `->` operator.

the `.` operator can be used only on structs, not on pointers to structs, for example: `(*begin).tv_sec` and not `begin.tv_sec` because begin is a pointer to struct. the operator `->` is just a "shortcut" for the above, for example `(*begin).tv_sec` is the same as `begin->tv_sec`